# monotouch: Image not displaying in email

Tags: html, xamarin.ios

I have some html that has an image in a table.  The table displays fine in a UIWebView.  I take that same html and send it in an email (using MFMailComposeViewController).  The code snippet to build the html is:

`html += "<tr><td><img src=\"reading.png\" align=left></td><td>"`

The table is created properly, but the image just has a question mark in a blue box.  (Obviously, it can't find the image, but why?)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sending the image too?

Comment: Hi Dimitris... yes, I want to, but it doesn't appear to go with the email for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The path "reading.png" is not found, that is the reason why you do not see the image.

There are in fact several potential solutions.

1) put the image to the web URL something like http://yourweb address.com/reading.png, this works well and will show, all the clients supports this and user just need to click to "show images" if he/she has it disabled by default in the email client.

2) second solution is to put the specific image representation to the img tag, you can do so by opening the file, reading its content and adding it as base64 data to the src of the img, there are plenty of samples for this.

3) third is to add it as attachment to the email. Again plenty of samples here and on the web how to do that.

Conversion of the sample code from ObjectiveC is simple to Monotouch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Pavel... I tried #3, since it appeared to be the easiest to implement... didn't find the image... this is what I have (in Monotouch):      _mail.AddAttachmentData(datas,"image/png", "reading.png");

Remembering that this is on the iPhone, I suppose I would have to supply a directory, but haven't a clue where it would store the image.

Comment: You cannot do that like this, you need the data to be the actual content of the image file and encoded to base64.

So load it with StreamReader from the storage, something like:
var path = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("reading", "png");
var sr = new StreamReader (path);
var content = sr.read <- read it here to buffer
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(content);

then add this to the AddAttachmentData call, then the attachment will be added.

Also note, that encoding a large portion of data will take some time on the iOS device.

Comment: Be warned: GMail and some other email readers do not like inline image data, as I just experienced :( So option 2 is no option either.